# (Django) automatic record creation for checklist?

Tags: python, django

I would like the user to be able to select a checklist for a project, however I believe the connection needs to be between the project and a checklist's items, not the checklist itself. This is to allow for an additional boolean field to mark whether an item has been completed for a specific project.

However I only want the user to select the checklist name - so how would I code the app to automatically create the appropriate junction_project_checks records upon selecting a checklist?

```
  project(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       checklist = models.ManyToManyField(checklist)

  checklist(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       checks = models.ManyToManyField(checks, through='junction_checklist_checks')

  checks(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       body = models.TextField()

  junction_checklist_checks(models.Model):
       checklist_id = models.ForeignKey(checklist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       checks_id = models.ForeignKey(checks, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

 junction_project_checks(models.Model):
       checks_id = models.ForeignKey(checks, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       project_id = models.ForeignKey(project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       checkbox = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: You create a new one with `myckecklist.checks.create(name='foo', body='bar')`?

Comment: Unless i'm misunderstanding, this would be creating new checks. However the checks are already created and associated with specific checklists, I'm refering to the associations betweens projects and checks. So if project 3 selects checklist 1, and checklist 1 contains checks 5-10 - I need an association between project 3 and checks 5-10 plus a boolean field for each. If the connection between project 3 and checklist 1 is deleted, these automatically created fields are deleted too.

Comment: then you use `mychecklist.checks.add(mycheck)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `checks` object with:

```
checklist.objects.get(name=name_of_list).checks.create(
    name='value-for-name', body='value-for-body'
)
```

Or if the check already exists, you can add it to a checklist:

```
checklist.objects.get(name=name_of_list).checks.add(
    checks.objects.get(name=name_of_check)
)
```

The modeling is however a bit "odd". It means that a `checks` object can belong to different lists, which is not per se that strange, but in some lists the `checks` is done, and in some others it is not.

> **Note**: normally a Django models, just like all classes in Python are given a name in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*, so it should be: `Check` instead of <s>`checks`</s>.

Comment: thank you for the help, if you have the time I'd really appreciate you taking a look at my other question - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700583/django-how-to-reference-through-multiple-layers-of-relationships)